# Infinite sum of positive semidefinite tempered distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence on non-positive functions $\{f_i(x)\}\in C({\mathbb R})$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i}f_i(x)$ has a moderate growth rate, e.g. polynomial. Let us denote the corresponding tempered distribution by $T_{f_i}$, i.e. $\langle T_{f_i}, \phi\rangle = \int f_i \phi$. Is it true that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \mathcal{F}[T_{f_i}]\rightarrow \mathcal{F}[f]
$$
in weak topology of ${\mathbb S}'({\mathbb R})$? Here $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.

Comment: Do you think that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$ converges to $f$ in the weak topology on $S'(\Bbb{R})$? As $\langle \widehat{g},\phi \rangle=\langle g,\widehat{\phi}\rangle$ and that the Fourier transform sends $S(\Bbb{R})$ to itself gives that this is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^n \widehat{f_i}$ converges to $\widehat{f}$.

Comment: Thank you. From your answer it is clear that non-positive functions $\{f_i(x)\}\in C({\mathbb R})$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)$ has a moderate growth rate satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n T_{f_i}\to T_f$ weakly, due to dominated convergence theorem. But can we omit the moderate growth rate condition. Is it enough that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)<\infty$?

Comment: If you set $f(0)=0$ then $f(x)=-1/|x|$ is finite everywhere but it doesn't give a distribution